# Why do my Eisenhower Cookies turn out flat?

Tags: cookies

This was my mother's recipe that my sisters and I have made several years. They use to work now they go flat. We are going nuts trying to figure out why. Any suggestion would be welcomed.

Eisenhower Cookies (really a ginger spice cookie)

```
2 cubes of margarine
1 cup and 3 tbsp sugar
1 well beaten egg
2 cups of flour (after sifting)
1 tsp cinammon
1 tsp ginger
2 tsp of baking soda
2 small pinch of salt
4 tbsp of yellow label molasses
```

Make into balls, roll in sugar, bake at 350 for about 10 minutes, depending on oven.

Comment: I changed the title a bit for clarification. What do you mean with flat?

Comment: @Brooke- some suggestions: check your oven's temperature with a thermometer, don't put dough on a hot cookie sheet, try non-insulated cookie sheets - they heat up faster so the cookie sets before it runs too much.

Comment: What kind of margarine are you using? If you've changed to tub/spread margarines then that could be the culprit as they have more water content than stick margarine.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried using fresh baking soda? I really don't see anything else that could be off here, especially if the recipe has worked well in the past.

Comment: yes.I have, i have tried using butter too but never shortening...Ok this is a crazy thought but would a hand mixer change the consitancy compare to a kitchen aid mixer. I now use a kitchen aid mixer...does it over beat the butter and sugar?

Comment: You get leavening problems from underbeating, not overbeating, so this shouldn't be the problem. Unless the mechanical action heats the butter to a stage where it is too soft and flows too early in the oven. Do you chill the cookies before baking?

Comment: yes.. I swear this problem has baffled us...It was our christmas cookie recipe that we all loved but nevermore....( i just watched the movie The Raven)..My sister and I just cannot figured it out. Would lowering the oven temperature help?

Comment: @brookegritch, as rumtscho indicates, maybe the butter gets too warm. You could leave the dough in the fridge for 20 minutes after beating.

Answer (score 2):

Over time ingredients change, equipment changes, etc. Your flour could get too moist, your molasses could have more water content, etc. Some suggestions:

- Use fresh dry ingredients
- Put your dough in the fridge to cool before you bake
- Give it a stiffer consistency by adding a tablespoon or two more flour. A little bit more isn't going to change the flavor noticeably

  - Raise the oven temperature a bit, lowering it will just make them run more before they set

Comment: I found a Martha Stewart chewy spice molassas cookie recipe that was so similar that I tried it out today. Pay dirt...it worked. The only ingredient that I change was I used ground ginger instead of the nutmeg. Tasted just like the ones mother used to make. YEA

Comment: well a year later I tried your tip on adding two extra tablespoons of flour and I am sure glad I did. It worked perfectly...now I finally have my mothers recipe to perfection. THANK YOU

Comment: Glad to hear it. I'm going to try the recipe.